# Pre-installed Apps and Extensions should not suggest Add-on and Google Apps Marketplace listings

Tags: google-apps, google-apps-marketplace

From the "Pre-installed Apps and Extensions" management in "Google Apps Admin console / Device management / Chrome / User settings / Apps and Extensions", the list of suggestions should only show Chrome extensions and Chrome applications.

Currently, it also shows "Google Drive Add-ons" and "Google Apps Marketplace applications", so, it's confusing for administrators because they don't know which one to select for automatic installation. Moreover, selecting a "Google Drive Add-on" or a "Google Apps Marketplace application" from "Pre-installed Apps and Extensions" has no effect.

For examples, you will find "Table of contents" (that is a Google Drive Add-on) and "LumDocs" (where you have a Chrome Application and a Google Apps Marketplace application).

Answer (score 0):

I was able to reproduce it so it's either a bug or expected behavior now that end users can install Google Apps Marketplace apps themselves.

This type of report should be submitted to the Google for Work team via phone or support.google.com/a > Contact Us. They'll be able to confirm the behavior and provide more details.

Comment: I was asked by Google themselves to leave a post in stackoverflow and to send them the link, as it was clearly identified as a bug